# Unable to build Xcode Project: clang error: linker command failed

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity project which I have successfully built for Android without issue.  When trying to build for iOS I am encountering an issue once the project is in Xcode.

Unity compiles without any errors and creates an Xcode project.

Upon opening the Xcode project I have *NO* simulators available.  I can get these simulators by selecting `ios` in the `Supported Platforms` section, at which point simulators become available - originally `Supported Platforms` is set to `iphoneos`.  This seems extremely odd behaviour to me, and suggests something larger going wrong.

After getting a simulator to select I get the following error when trying to compile/run/build:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The full error is available on Pastebin (too large to post directly on here):

https://pastebin.com/3fYR8fE3

I'm really at a loss on what I can do.  I have tried a number of things, including:

- Building from Unity as Debug and Release
- Building from Unity with 'Symlink Unity Libraries' on and off
- Building from Unity with .Net 3.5 and .Net 4.* flavours
- Manually adding the  `libiconv.2.dylib` file in the linked frameworks tab as the `.tbd` equivalent
- Setting the target minimum version of iOS to 9.0 (negates the need for libiconv.2.dylib entirely)

I am using latest versions of everything:

- Unity 2018.2.17f1
- Xcode 10.1

Comment: have you tried building on real device instead of simulator?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have the library il2cpp built for another architecture, have you tried to change your target's "Build Settings > Build Active Architectures Only" to "No"?
However I made some researches and it seems that Unity for iPhone doesn't deploy on simulator. It only works on device or in the Unity editor. Check [this link](https://answers.unity.com/questions/20774/problem-with-linking-internal-xcode-frameworks.html) out